# JavaScript: How browser consoles displays the object key values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, undefined, google-chrome-console

From the Chrome console :

```
> myParam = {"test": "test value"}    
> myFunc = function(x) { myParam[x] = x; }

> myFunc("func value")
> myParam
{test: "test value", func value: "func value"} // (a) question

> myFunc(2)
> myParam
{2: 2, test: "test value", func value: "func value"}

> myFunc()
> myParam
{2: 2, test: "test value", func value: "func value", undefined: undefined} // (b) question
```

this is the latest version of Chrome to day (69.0.3497.100)
[image]
Please explain how, in JavaScript

a) can be created an object member containing spaces ("myParam.func value")
  b) can be created an "undefined" object member ("myParam.undefined")
  c) for the (b) case, is the "undefined" really "undefined" or just a string "undefined" ?

---

**PS.** Thanks to the @ryanpcmcquen's remark, the following PS
[image]

---

**PPS.** Could you confirm my supposition that this is a Google Chrome v(69.0.3497.100) **console display bug** if the *strings are not displayed like strings*, "between brackets" and in red color?

---

**PPS.**
Only **Firefox** seems to correctly display the string keys:

**Chrome, Opera**
[image]
**Firefox**
[image]
**Edge**
[image]
**MS IE**
[image]

Comment: All answers can be found here: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: @Andreas fortunately you didn't send me http://google.com as help link. What about the c) question?

Comment: I will refer you again to my link, because there all your questions will be answered.

Comment: @Andreas the confusing moment is how the Google Chrome displays keys, it should display the keys like strings, cause there's strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering object `foo`:

```
var foo = {};
```

a) can be created an object member containing spaces ("myParam.func value")

```
// You have to use square bracket notation when
// declaring properties with spaces.
foo['func value'] = 'Whatever you want.';
```

b) can be created an "undefined" object member ("myParam.undefined")

```
// Keyword undefined:
foo[undefined] = undefined;
// String 'undefined':
foo['undefined'] = 'undefined';
```

c) for the (b) case, is the "undefined" really "undefined" or just a string "undefined"?

Depends on how you define it. In your screenshot it is the keyword `undefined` for the property value, and the string `'undefined'` for the key.

To verify the types inside your object you can run:

```
Object.keys(foo).map(key => typeof key);
Object.values(foo).map(value => typeof value);
```

Comment: remark the difference for "func value" is not a string in the OP case (not included in brackets when displayed in the Google Console)

Comment: so, not `foo['func value'] = 'xxx';` but `foo[func value] = 'xxx';`

Comment: @Serge, that is not valid JavaScript. `foo[func value]` would imply a computed property name or variable. That is not what is happening here.

Comment: have a look on the console output in the OP example (a) case

Comment: @Serge, just because it doesn't look like a string does not mean it is not a string. Run this on your object: `Object.keys(myParam).map(key => typeof key);`

Comment: you are trying to say, Google does not display correctly the strings in console?

Comment: @Serge, you could interpret it that way. If my answer has clarified your questions, please accept it, otherwise let me know if there is anything else that is unclear.

Comment: @Serge, I think this is how the display is intended to look, and not a bug. It is worth noting though, that Firefox displays object keys as strings.

Answer (score 0):

This is the one of the beauties of JavaScript.

a) We can create object keys with spaces, since object keys can be strings. when you want to see the value of object whose keys are String you need to do that in the following manner

```
var a = {
  'my key': 'my key'
  yourKey: 'your key'
}
a['my key'];
a.yourKey
```

b) In JavaScript undefined is a type of data, so that is perfectly legal to have variable whose value is undefined

c) It really is undefined. See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: in my case is `a[my key]` (without brackets) for the (a) case

Comment: yes, but you are passing it as an argument to the function - as x, and its value is string my key

Comment: yes, but you can see in console, is not surrounded by brackets as it would be for a string

Comment: JavaScript is treating it as if it is a string

Comment: I know that this can be strange for someone coming from C#. It was strange for me too, but that is JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

**Lets answer your questions.**

**a)**  can be created an object member containing spaces ("myParam.func value")

```js
const myParam = {}
myParam["func value"] = 'serge';
console.log(myParam)
```

**Yes**, but a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number can only be accessed using the square bracket notation

**b)** can be created an "undefined" object member ("myParam.undefined")

**Yes**. An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string

```js
const myParam = {};
myParam.undefiend = 'serge';
console.log(myParam)
```

**c)** for the (b) case, is the "undefined" really "undefined" or just a string "undefined" ?

I guess it's string "undefined"

Comment: for the (b) case, the `undefined` is *NOT* a string, nor an empty string, as I understand, but the really `undentified` value

Comment: Yeah my bad, I was not sure on that really. THanks for correcting me.

Comment: for (c) you ques is alpha, but in reality you think is beta?

Comment: @Serge Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Serge it’s important to note that javascript object keys are **aways strings**. If you try to set/get a field from a javascript object with a expression that is _not_ a string, that expression will be **coerced** to a string.

Answer (score -3):

Answer for c "undefined" usually towards to "null" value, you can console.log(null) and you can find the undefined

Comment: In the case of this question, the value `undefined` has been cast to a string. This is because JS object property names must be strings.